P12 cert password encryption in java springboot application ( using yml )
In my Java spring boot application, I'm using a P12 certificate and jks to connect to MQ for message reading & sending. the details of jks and p12 are stored & referred to via yml files. we need all passwords encrypted which, when I tried is throwing an error for p12 ( jks successful ).
ymlfiles are as such:
ssl:
  key-store: file path of p12
  key-password : password
  key-store-password : password
  trust-store-password: password

For client TLS Config, the class is calling the path, password as :
@value("$ssl.key-password}")
private String keypassword

similar for trust store password and keystore password

and to create ssl context :
@Bean
public SSLContext sslContext() {
SSLContext sslcont=SSLContextbuilder.create()
                                    ....

                                    .keypassword.toCharArray().....build();
}

i introduced a decryption encryption class, encrypted the password in yml & changed above code to :
@Bean
public SSLContext sslContext() {
SSLContext sslcont=SSLContextbuilder.create()
                                    ....

                                    .encryptor.decrypt(keypassword).toCharArray().....build();
}

sslContext Bean is in a @configuration class. should i autowire import the encryptor class inside the bean ? i suspect as it is a @value called detail, maybe somewhere inside the other beans in the class it is called as encrypted & thorws error ?
But i get below errors everytime:
keystore password was incorrect
badpaddingexception

I have rechecked the password, encryptions etc. Please help !

we need all passwords encrypted  I'm pretty sure Spring Boot uses the passwords as-is from its configuration file.  Where would the the decryption key come from?  Another file on disk?  If storing the passwords in the file were insecure, Spring Boot wouldn't do that.  You need to protect access to the file.

decryption, encryption & the secret key is stored in the encryption class, code not exposed, yml is exposed

decryption, encryption & the secret key is stored in the encryption class, code not exposed No.  You didn't hardcode keys into your code and just now claim the keys are "not exposed", did you?  They're leaked to every system of every developer who checks out the code.  There leaked into every system that stores your code repo.  They're leaked to every system that runs your delivered code.  And probably a whole lot more.  You have an utterly insecure system.

sorry that is not the answer I am looking for

The real question you should be asking is how to fix your system so that it's not flagrantly insecure.  What you have is broken and encrypting the passwords gets you nothing.  You might encrypt the passwords, but you then put the entire decryption mechanism right there with the "safe" encrypted passwords.  What you've done is taped the key to your home's door right on the doorknob outside with a big sign that says "Here's the key to get in!"  And then you think you're safe because you locked the door.
